# Spliting a csv file based on the value of one column

Tags: powershell, csv, split, xlsx, xls

I have a csv file that I have to split based on the value of a column.
I'm using the following script to do so:

```
Import-Csv test.csv | Group-Object -Property "Nr dep" | 
Foreach-Object {$path=$_.name+".csv" ; $_.group | 
Export-Csv -Path E:\PowerShell\script\$path -NoTypeInformation}
```

The file is split to files based on the `Nr dep` value column but with quotes and it works only with comma delimited csv files.
I tried to use `-replace` but still no result (maybe I'am writing it in a bad manner)

```
Import-Csv test.csv | Group-Object -Property "Nr dep" | 
Foreach-Object {$path=$_.name+".csv" ; ($_.group | 
ConvertTo-Csv  -NoTypeInformation)  -replace '"', "" | Out-File E:\PowerShell\script\$path -Force}
```

1) How can I make the delimitation a semi comma instead of a comma
2) how can I get rid of the quotes
3) is it possible to have an .xlsx outfile instead of a .csv file

Answer (score 0):

1) You can specify the delimiter by using the `-Delimiter` parameter:

```
Import-Csv test.csv -Delimiter ';'
```

2) By using `-replace '"'` which you already do.

3) You will need a framework // application for that.

Comment: @Clijsters 3) is not wrong. PSExcel is also using a dll.

Comment: For the -replace in fact as shown in my question I thought it would be the solution but once i've added it the script, I have no error but I have no result in the specified output file

Comment: @MartinBrandl But not a framework or external application. It just implements EPPlus.

Comment: @Clijsters Its still a library. If you have a solution using *plain* PowerShell I will edit my answer.